# chromium mouse cursor is not changing, how to fix?

Tags: google-chrome

So, when hovering over links, or anything else on the chromium window, the mouse cursor will not change, it will remain the last one that changed because of some click event.

How to fix it?

I am on ubuntu linux , I am using latest chromium 53.0.2785.143-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1145
I have an NVidia GeForce GTS 250

Comment: I didnt search here, only at webapps, and as I believed my Chrome was working, I looked specifically for chromium... but this is a duplicate indeed, even the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I actually already had the answer, but as I found it by luck, I thought it would be good to document it here.

So here is the [answer](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=456222#c196).

basically, on chromium:
Menu:Edit/preferences:Settings->Show Advanced Settings
Uncheck the box that says "Use hardware acceleration when available"